# Doxygen's call/caller graph references missing for Fortran functions

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I try to generate a call/caller graph for a fixed-form Fortran code using Doxygen 1.8.11 using Dot (GraphViz 2.38).

The call/caller graph works fine for subroutines, but fails (i.e. no references is drawn) for functions with a declared return value.

i.e.  for the following code, the call to `MYFUNC` is not shown in the call graph of `MYSUB`:

```
  integer function MYFUNC()
    implicit none
    MYFUNC = 1
  end function

  subroutine MYSUB ()
    implicit NONE
    integer MYFUNC
    integer RESULT
    RESULT = MYFUNC()
  return
  end
```

Interestingly, if I remove the line `integer MYFUNC` from `MYSUB`, the call graph is drawn correctly, but the code is not valid anymore (i.e., it does not compile).

Is there an option to include function calls in the call/caller graph?

Comment: If you specify explicitly the (already implied) `external` attribute, does that help.  Such as `integer, external :: myfunc` or an `external myfunc`?

Comment: @francescalus no, it does not help

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 6567, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6567 :  Handling Fortran functions in call graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is because Doxygen doesn't understand that `MYFUNC` in `MYSUB` is the same thing as the function `MYFUNC`.
You can generate the caller graph for `MYFUNC` by writing an `interface` block for it in `MYSUB`, but this doesn't generate the call graph for `MYSUB`.

In order to get Doxygen to correctly generate the call/caller graph, you should put the two procedures in a module (alternatively, you can put them in their own separate modules). This also removes the need to define `MYFUNC` in `MYSUB`:

```
module foo

  implicit none

contains

  integer function myfunc()
    myfunc = 1
  end function myfunc

  subroutine mysub (res)
    integer res
    res = myfunc()
  end subroutine mysub

end module foo
```

Additionally, Doxygen doesn't seem to generate the call/caller graphs for procedures with uppercase names, at least in version 1.8.8. I have `CASE_SENSE_NAMES = YES` in my Doxyfile, so I suspect that is a bug.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I'm analyzing some legacy code, moving the functions to modules is no option at the moment. As a workaround, I just removed the declariation of the function as a variable (i.e. commented out `integer MYFUNC`)